# "Постоянная арена – Колизей стал настоящим подарком"?

Tags: пунктуация, согласование

> Император Веспасиан, в свою очередь, был прославлен как устроитель
>   Колизея (театров в Риме было много, но по большей части они являлись
>   временными конструкциями – возводились на праздники). **Постоянная арена
>   – Колизей стал настоящим подарком.**

Не надо портить на:

*Постоянная арена – Колизей – стала настоящим подарком.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Постоянная арена – Колизей стал настоящим подарком.**

У Розенталя (ставится одно тире): http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

3) если приложение стоит перед определяемым словом: Один из аутсайдеров чемпионата страны — спортсмены клуба «Фили» одержали третью победу подряд (Газ.); Глашатай лесов — кукушка известила всех о событии;

Я  думаю, что в этих предложениях  приложение имеет дополнительное обстоятельственное значение (хотя, будучи). На месте тире делается пауза, которая делит предложение на две части.

Будучи постоянной ареной, Колизей стал настоящим подарком.